# Rails flash messages: is there a good reason they work the way they do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The Rails 'flash' message system is very useful, but I've always found the details of its implementation make its use awkward.

Specifically, the flash messages are cleared at the end of a response. This means that you have to work out whether they're going to be used in a direct page render or a redirect, then inform the flash system by using 'now' if it's not a redirect.

This seems overly complex and error-prone.

Occasionally I find myself building things that need to exhibit flash-like behaviour, and the process I use is slightly different:

```
class FlashlikeStore

  attr_accessor :session

  def initialize(session)
    session[:flashlike] ||= []
    self.session = session
  end

  def add(name, data)
    self.store << { name: name, data: data }
  end

  def read
    session.delete(:flashlike).to_json
  end

  def any?
    store && store.any?
  end

  protected

  def store
    session[:flashlike]
  end

end
```

With a little syntactic sugar in the application helper I can easily add my name-value pairs, and the act of reading it deletes the data. (In this case I'm actually reading this in via AJAJ, but that isn't important here.)

The upshot is that messages are only ever read once, with no need up-front to determine or guess when they're going to appear. They're read when they're needed, then they go away.

One could argue, I suppose, that a call to an object shouldn't both read data and change state, so the 'read' method could be split into a 'read' and a 'wipe' if you wanted to be purist that way. (Although you probably wouldn't be using Rails if you were.)

So the question is this: am I missing something? Is there a compelling reason for the way Rails flash messaging works, with its need for the 'now' method?

Comment: What if you don't read it at the right time? Will the message hang around and potentially appear when it shouldn't? The point of flashes are that they don't hang around longer than their relevancy.

Comment: .now on render, no .now on redirect.  Seems very convenient to me :P

Comment: @Matt: potentially, yes. Although presumably you want the message to actually get to the user, so if something went so wrong that an extra page load happened without the flash message displaying (I'm struggling to think of a situation where this could happen) then the user would get the information. Yes, relevancy would suffer, but as every page render should draw (and thus delete) the flash messages, this situation should never arise.

Comment: @AFaderDarkly But if you're always going to do things perfectly - how is the existing system more "error prone" than yours?

Comment: @bkunzi01: More convenient is not having to care about whether to use .now or not. This way, the code used to send a message can be decoupled from the rendering or redirecting logic and code can become cleaner.

Comment: @Matt: The fewer moving parts in a machine, the less there is to go wrong. Using 'now' (or not) is an extra decision the developer needs to make, every time the system is used, which could result in messages disappearing. Removing this decision means the scope of potential errors in the code is reduced. However, relevancy is not a bad argument...